# Prolem with parallel openmp multi loop in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I wrote a program to find key with 8 loops.
It takes me 2 hours to found key.
Now i want to use openmp to reduce the time but i can't get it to work, it found nothing.
Please help me i'm new to openmp, thank you.

```
int main()
{
    cout << endl;
    clock_t start, end;
    cout << "\nStart\n";
    start = clock();
    int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(12)
    {
#pragma omp for collapse(8)
        for (i1 = 'a'; i1 <= 'z'; i1++)
            for (i2 = 'a'; i2 <= 'z'; i2++)
                for (i3 = 'a'; i3 <= 'z'; i3++)
                    for (i4 = 'a'; i4 <= 'z'; i4++)
                        for (i5 = 'a'; i5 <= 'z'; i5++)
                            for (i6 = 'a'; i6 <= 'z'; i6++)
                                for (i7 = 'a'; i7 <= 'z'; i7++)
                                    for (i8 = 'a'; i8 <= 'z'; i8++)
                                    {
                                        unsigned short ot_2[6] = { 0x66c0, 0xc5cc, 0x0bcd ,0x7201, 0x0923,0xfc29 };
                                        unsigned short wt_2[6] = { 0xdb93, 0xe790, 0x1dc0 ,0xbf79, 0x1fdf,0x5bdb };
                                        unsigned short Key[4];
                                        Key[0] = ((i1 << 8) ^ i2);
                                        Key[1] = ((i3 << 8) ^ i4);
                                        Key[2] = ((i5 << 8) ^ i6);
                                        Key[3] = ((i7 << 8) ^ i8);
                                        if (encrypt(ot_2[0], Key) == wt_2[0])
                                            if (encrypt(ot_2[1], Key) == wt_2[1])
                                                if (encrypt(ot_2[2], Key) == wt_2[2])
                                                    if (encrypt(ot_2[3], Key) == wt_2[3])
                                                        if (encrypt(ot_2[4], Key) == wt_2[4])
                                                            if (encrypt(ot_2[5], Key) == wt_2[5])
                                                                printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8);
                                    }
    }
    end = clock();
    double time = (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    int hour = time / 60 / 60, minutes = (time - hour * 60 * 60) / 60, second = time - hour * 60 * 60 - minutes * 60;
    cout << "Time: " << hour << ":" << minutes << ":" << second << endl;
}
```

I'm using g++ on windows by the way.

Update: here's the encrypt funtion

```
unsigned short encrypt(unsigned short x, unsigned short Key[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        x ^= Key[i];
        x = (Pi[x & 0xf] ^ (Pi[(x >> 4) & 0xf] << 4) ^ (Pi[x >> 8 & 0xf] << 8) ^ (Pi[x >> 12 & 0xf] << 12));
        x = functionP(x);
    }
    x ^= Key[2];
    x = (Pi[x & 0xf] ^ (Pi[(x >> 4) & 0xf] << 4) ^ (Pi[x >> 8 & 0xf] << 8) ^ (Pi[x >> 12 & 0xf] << 12));
    x ^= Key[3];
    return x;
}
```

Here's functionP

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<time.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
unsigned char Pi[16] = { 0xa,5,6,4,0xb,3,0xd,0x9,0xc,0xf,0xe,0,7,1,0x8,2 };
unsigned char P[16] = { 0, 4, 8, 12, 1, 5, 9, 13, 2, 6, 10, 14, 3, 7, 11, 15 };
unsigned short functionP(unsigned short x)
{
    unsigned short temp = x;
    x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        x ^= (((temp >> (15 - P[i])) & 0x1) << (15 - i));
    return x;
}
```

Comment: `if (encrypt(ot_2[4], Key) == wt_2[5])` is not symmetric with the other `if` statements. Is that correct?

Comment: Does it work without OpenMP? If not, then the problem is not with parallelization.

Comment: It works with out OpenMP. I just dont know how to use it with openMp.

Comment: I mean without openMP, the program works fine, key found. With openMP, it found nothing.

Comment: The OpenMP specifications are [here](https://www.openmp.org/specifications/). If the parallelization does not work but it does when single-threaded then it is probably because you have some shared variables. ot_2, Key and wt_2 seem to be likely candidates. ["2.21.1 Data Sharing Attribute Rules"](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu113.html) of the specification appears to be the relevant section. Are these variables shared or not?

Comment: You need to ensure `ot_2` is not shared across threads otherwise multiple threads are constantly overwriting into the same memory. Same goes for `Key`. Can you show the definitions of the arrays you are using.

Comment: `Pi` and `P` are defined in `encrypt` and `functionP` respectively but do not appear to be defined anywhere in your code. Where is it?

Comment: Your loop variables are shared. Please use the syntax `for (int i3=.....` to make the local and private.

Comment: @ThắngVũ Please, delete all the comments about updates you made to the question (as I did about their requests). They are no more relevant and make the discussion here off-topic.

Comment: Is 'snegovik' the expected output?

Comment: @Laci yes it is!

Comment: @Laci so what is the problem with my code? Can you tell me please, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: As the OP is new is openMP, I have added more details to my answer.

The problem is with your code is that the collapsed loops has altogether 25^8=152,587,890,625 iterations, which is bigger than the maximum of (32 bit) `int` (2,147,483,647). The compiler (g++ 10.2) cannot handle this situation and produce incorrect code. There are 2 solutions to handle it:

1. use `long long` instead of `int`. In this case collapsing all the loops is not a problem for the compiler.
2. Remove `collapse(8)` or change it to `collapse(n) n=2..6`. If you remove `collapse(8)` the above mentioned problem is solved, but in this case your loop variables (`i2,i3,..i8`) become shared, as they are not loop variables of the parallel loop construct anymore and defined outside the parallel region. It causes data race as they used by different threads and gives incorrect result. Note that the loop variables (of the parallel loop construct) are privatized by the compiler so `i1` is private by default, and if you use `collapse(8)` all the loop variables are privatized. To make your loop variables private you can explicitly set it by the `private` clause:

   `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(12) private(i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8)`
   Since you are new to openMP, it is a good practice to use `default(none)` clause, so you are forced to define the sharing attribute of all of your variables. If you forget to do so, you will receive a compiler error.
   `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(12) default(none) private(i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8)`

Another comment is you should always define your variables in their minimum required scope. Since the loop variables are not used after the loop it is much better to define them in the *init-statement* of for loop:

```
for (int i1 = 'a'; i1 <= 'z'; i1++)
```

In this case variables `i1,i2..i8` defined inside the parallel region, so they are private by default, so you do not have not to worry about them. Note also that the 2 openmp directives can be merged to a so-called combined directive, so putting it together your code will look like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) num_threads(12) collapse(6)
        for (int i1 = 'a'; i1 <= 'z'; i1++)
            for (int i2 = 'a'; i2 <= 'z'; i2++)
                for (int i3 = 'a'; i3 <= 'z'; i3++)
                    for (int i4 = 'a'; i4 <= 'z'; i4++)
                        for (int i5 = 'a'; i5 <= 'z'; i5++)
                            for (int i6 = 'a'; i6 <= 'z'; i6++)
                                for (int i7 = 'a'; i7 <= 'z'; i7++)
                                    for (int i8 = 'a'; i8 <= 'z'; i8++)
                                    { .....
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm trying it now! How long did it take you to take the result?

Comment: Start 
snegovikTime: 1:31:39  (g++-10 -O3 -fopenmp). I think this is the processor time, it took just a few mins on 16 cores.

Comment: can you send your full code to tkhangvu97@gmail.com please, so i can test. I just learn openMP today so it's very new to me.

Comment: OK. ps: real    5m57.490s   
user    95m10.741s

Comment: it worked. But i wonder if i delete 'collapse(6)', will it still work? Or will it work with 'collapse(3)' or 'collapse(1)'?

Comment: Short answer is yes, but I will edit my answer and give you a more detailed answer soon...

Comment: Thank you i'm waiting! Very appreciate that.

Comment: Rather than declaring variables in the outer scope and then having to worry about their sharing properties (and declare some `private`) you might like to catch up with the ultra-modern features of C99 :-) and declare variables in their minimum required scope...

Comment: @Jim, thanks for the comment, I have changed "minimal scope" to "minimum required scope" which is much better. Well, I am not a native English speaker, but I think I have told the same thing to the OP in my answer.